# You have tried to set a null level to root

Tags: c#, log4net

I was able to create a log file before using log4net.But now Iam getting the following error"You have tried to set a null level to root." I googled but couldnt find anything..Someone please help me on this...

This is my log4net.config file...It includes code for creating a coloured html log file..

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>

<log4net>
  <root>
    <level Value="Info"/>
    <level Value="Error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredFileAppender" />
  </root>

  <appender name="ColoredFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
    <file value="C:\Logs\CL2.html" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%CC" />
       <converter>
         <name value="CC" />
         <type value="Cluster2.ColoredMessageConverter" />
       </converter>
       <mapping>
         <level value="Info" />
         <foreColor value="Green" />
       </mapping>
       <mapping>
         <level value="ERROR" />
         <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
       </mapping>
     </layout>
   </appender>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

Anyhelp would be really appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your config?

Comment: A screenshot is unlikely to be as helpful as a combination of your code, configuration, and a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing one of the level tags under the `<root>` element. If I understand the [schema](http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd) correctly, you can only specify a single log level.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual error is triggered because you have `Value` instead of `value` for the level attribute.

However, as Anders has pointed out, you can only have one level

So instead of

```
<root>
    <level Value="Info"/>
    <level Value="Error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredFileAppender" />
</root>
```

you should have

```
<root>
   <level value="Error"/>
   <appender-ref ref="ColoredFileAppender" />
 </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code below. I am using log4net as well and this is how I set up my config. Which framework are you working with ?

```xml
 <log4net>
    <root>
      <priority value="Info" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Temp\Application.API.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
      <maximumFileSize value="15000KB" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="{%level}%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %C{1}.%M - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```